# Form recogniser - Setup Issues

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

For the Form recognizer sample code provided in the below link, the Python interpreter cannot recognize Azure core API’s.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=ga%2Cv2-0&pivots=programming-language-python)

```
python —version 
-Python 3.9.1
pip3 —version
- ip 21.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'azure'
  File "/Users/visiothoughts/Documents/Visiothoughts/Work-Project/AI-Moto/com/ai/Bill-Recogniser/RecogniseFormContent.py", line 5, in <module>
    from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
```

Can I get some guidance on what is missing?

Comment: Hi @Raj - a few questions: 1) if you run a `pip list`, does it show that you have azure-ai-formrecognizer and azure-core installed? 2) are you running this code in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the module for Azure-Core has not been installed.

Run

```
pip install azure-core
```

Since the error you re receiving is below :

```
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
```